# 私まで嬉しい is translated as "I am happy", what function of まで is this?

Tags: particle-まで

Why is it used this way instead of は for example?

Comment: got more context?

Answer (score 5):

The まで means "even".

According to 明鏡国語辞典:

> まで ㊁〘副助詞〙
>   ❶ 極端なものを例示して、他はましてと暗示する。「君**まで**僕を疑うのか」「親に**まで**見限られるとは」

It is used to show an extreme example, implying that some other thing(s) is/are much more so.

> 私**まで**嬉しい。
>   　　
>   "*Even* I am happy (as well as someone. / and others are much more so)."
>   (It's closer to 私**も**嬉しい "I'm happy, too" than 私**は**嬉しい "I'm happy.")

An example from Shogakukan's Progressive Japanese-English Dictionary:

> 老人**まで**踊っている。 **Even** old people are dancing.

Answer (score 1):

> 私まで嬉しい is translated as “I am happy”, what function of まで is this?

This まで is used in the same sense as 雨が降りだして**風まで**出てきた, or **私まで**しかられるなんて.

The speaker is saying "I am happy though I have not much to do with it". There are other people directly involved with the incident they are talking about.